# Поход по бассейну?

Tags: выбор-слов

Предложение «...в походе по бассейну реки». Звучит нормально? Меня смущает «поход по бассейну».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, можно пойти в поход по воде:
[image]

Ещё есть водные походы:
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Водный_туризм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC)

Comment: так можно или нет?

Comment: Получается, что да. Но мало кто об этом знает, это профессиональное.